# Python - read numpy array from file

Tags: python, numpy

I have an input file formatting as follow:

```
* 1 *
[[1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0] [ 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0]] [1.5 2.5 3.5]

* 2 *
[[8.0 7.0 6.0 5.0] [ 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0]] [4.5 5.5 6.5]
```

Sizes of matrix and vector are not known. I would like to get the number inside stars, the matrix and the vector into 3 differents variables (`it`, `mtx`, `vect`).

I would like to know if there is an easy way to read the matrix and vector in numpy.array ?
I succeed to get the number inside the stars however for the line where there are the matrix `mtx` and the vector `vect`, i can't find a quick and proper way to do it.

Here a sample of my code, where i'm trying to get the vector but where i have this error `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

import numpy
import re

def read(filename):
    it = 0
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if line[0] == '*':
                it += 1

    v_it = numpy.zeros((it)).astype(numpy.int32)
    mtx = numpy.array((it,)).astype(numpy.float32)
    vect = numpy.array((it,)).astype(numpy.float32)
    a = 0
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if line[0] == '*':
                print int(line[2:-2])
                v_it[a] = int(line[2:-2])
            elif line[:2] == '[[':
                idx = line.index(']]')
                line = line[idx+4:-2]
                line = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', line)
                vect[a] = numpy.fromstring(line, dtype=numpy.float32, sep=' ')
                print vect[a]
            elif line == '':
                a += 1
                print a
    print vect

if __name__ == "__main__":
    read('input.txt')
```

If someone could tell me how to read the vector (or at least which librairy to use), i should be able to read the matrix as well.
Any help would be appreciate

Comment: what's the file format?

Comment: The file is just a text file (`*.txt`) which contains some results (i put the exact format at the beginning of my request where i just change the data for simplicity). Matrices and vectors contain float numbers. Number inside stars are integers. Hope this answers your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i found a solution, i share it in case someone needs to deal with the same problem.

I change `vect` from `numpy.array` to `[]`.
Then i append each vector in `vect` one at a time.
Finally, i cast `vect` to a `numpy.array`.

Here the lines that changed (with in comment what was previously there):

```
# Before the with
vect = [] # numpy.array((it,)).astype(object)

# In with.for.elif
line = line[idx+4:-2]
l = [float(ll) for ll in line.split()] # line = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', line)
vect.append(numpy.array(l).astype(numpy.float32)) # numpy.fromstring([...])

# Outside the with
vect = numpy.array(vect)
```

At the end i got a 2D numpy.array which contains the vectors from my input file.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use pandas and do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
H = pd.read_csv('test.txt',header=None)
blocks = H[1::2].as_matrix()
names = H[::2].as_matrix()
v_it = [int(i[0][2:-2]) for i in names]
mtx = []
vect = []
for i in blocks:
    imtx, ivect = eval(i[0].replace(' ', ',').replace('[,','['))
    mtx.append(imtx)
    vect.append(ivect)
```